# Meaning of the phrase "displace oneself" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here it goes:

> Psychologically, 20RM work is very hard, due to the pain, and lifters who are good at it develop the ability to **displace themselves** from the situation during the set. Or they just get very tough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **displace yourself** would mean to step outside yourself psychologically, to become "detached" from the pain.